# Sum columns with a column as a chr type

Tags: r, sum, dataframe, chr

I have something like this:

```
Date        Point1 Point2 Point3
01-03-2000     23     57    98
02-03-2000     67     36    77 
03-03-2000     67     25    47 
...
```

I wanna get the sum of each column with a function like `colSums`, but my first column it isn't numeric, is a character type. How do I get the sum?

Answer (score 5):

If `dat` is your data frame, you could try

```
colSums(dat[ , -1])
```

This will return the sum of each column except the first one (the one with the dates).

Answer (score 4):

A more generalisable solution:

```
# set up some fake data with text and numeric columns 
numchr <- list(1:3,letters[1:3])
test <- data.frame(numchr[sample(1:2,10,replace=TRUE)])
names(test) <- letters[1:10]

# which looks like...
> test
  a b c d e f g h i j
1 1 a a a a 1 a 1 1 a
2 2 b b b b 2 b 2 2 b
3 3 c c c c 3 c 3 3 c

# get the sums only for the numeric columns
colSums(test[sapply(test,is.numeric)])

a f h i 
6 6 6 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (using @thelatemail's example):

```
library(plyr)
numcolwise(sum)(test)
```